# Loop adding letter to a tile

Tags: arrays, if-statement, for-loop, multidimensional-array, nested-loops

This bit of code is supposed to be adding a letter to a single tile, but the way it's currently written it's adding a letter to several tiles. How do I fix that? Thanks.

```
public void add(char c) {
        for (int row = 0; row < 4; row++){
            for (int col = 0; col < 4; col++){
                if (tiles[row][col] != null && tiles[row][col].getLetter() == null){
                    tiles[row][col].setLetter(letters.pop());
                    notifyObservers();
                    break;
                }
            }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `break;` only exits the inner loop: `for (int col = 0; col < 4; col++)`

So it still runs the outter loop: `for (int row = 0; row < 4; row++)` and therefore re-enters the inner loop again
Try replacing `break;` with a `return;` to exit the `add(char c)` function completly. Thus preventing any further loop itterations

```
public void add(char c) {
    for (int row = 0; row < 4; row++){
        for (int col = 0; col < 4; col++){
            if (tiles[row][col] != null && tiles[row][col].getLetter() == null){
                tiles[row][col].setLetter(letters.pop());
                notifyObservers();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```